# TCP connection and a different buffer size for a client and a server

Tags: sockets, tcp, buffer, network-protocols

What will happen if I will establish a connection between a client and a server, and configure a different buffer size for each of them.

This is my client's code:

```
 import socket,sys

TCP_IP = sys.argv[1]
TCP_PORT = int(sys.argv[2])
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "World! Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

Server's code:

```
 import socket,sys

TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = int(sys.argv[1])
BUFFER_SIZE = 5

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'New connection from:', addr
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        print "received:", data
        conn.send(data.upper()) 
    conn.close()
```

That means I will be limited to only 5 bytes? Which means I won't be able to receive the full packet and will lose 1024-5 packets?
I or does it mean I am able to get only packets of 5 bytes, which means that instead of receiving one packets of 1024 bytes as the client sent it, I'll have to divide 1024 by 5 and get 204.8 packets (?) which sounds not possible.

What in general is happing in that code?

Thanks.

Comment: (removed [tag:protocol-buffers] - that's a specific serialization format, *not* general things about buffers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arguments are based on the assumption that a single `send` should match a single `recv`. But this is not the case. TCP is a byte stream and not a message based protocol. This means all what matters are the transferred bytes. And for this is does not matter if it does not matter if one or 10 `recv` are needed to read 50 bytes.

Apart from that `send` is not guaranteed to send the full buffer either. It might only send parts of the buffer, i.e. the sender need actually check the return code to find out how much of the given buffer was actually send now and how much need to be retried for sending later.

And note that the underlying "packet" is again a different thing. If there is a `send` for 2000 bytes it will usually need multiple packets to be send (depending on the maximum transfer unit of the underlying data link layer). But this does not mean that one also need multiple `recv`. If all the 2000 bytes are already transferred to the OS level receive buffer at the recipient then they can be also be read at once, even if they traveled in multiple packets.

Comment: So, how can a sender check the return code (ACK)? I mean in the given codes, where does the sender check the return code? And what about the different buffer sizes here? What exactly will happen? By what you told me, the sender will send the message a lot faster than the receiver will receive it. But the receiver will receive the full message. And then what? It will send it slowly and by upper case?

Comment: @DimaCiun: First, there are no "messages", only bytes. Then, `send` will return how many bytes are put in the sockets send buffer and does not reflect anything ACKed or by the peer system, read or even processed by the peer application. And yes, the sender might automatically slow down after a while - if the send buffer is full the `send` will block. And the send buffer will only be emptied if the data are ACKed by the peer. See for example [TCP Flow Control](https://www.brianstorti.com/tcp-flow-control/) for more details on this.

Comment: So in my case, the sender can send segments of maximum size of 1024 bytes But the server can only receive 5 bytes. So The sender will expect an ACK for "1025" which means 0-1025 are received, but will get ACK only for 5 (0-5) so it will think that 1000+ bytes are lost and will send again the first packet?

Comment: @DimaCiun: The recipient OS (not application) will receive the 1024 and send the ACK for all of these. These 1024 bytes will be put in the receive buffer associated with the socket - which is not the buffer used in the application. The application will then read 5 bytes from this receive buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket won't lose the remaining 1024 - 5 (1019) bytes.it just stored on the socket and ready to read again! so , all you need to do is to read from the socket again. the size of buffer you want to read to is decided by yourself. and you are not limited to 5 bytes, you are just limiting the read buffer for each single read to 5 bytes. so for 1024 bytes to read you have to read for 204 times plus another time read which would be the last one. but remember that the last time read fills your last buffer index with null. and that means there is no more bytes available for now.